# Using linq to check if not exists clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, join, union

Here is situation I have been trying to solve

Lets take a Employee table

```
Create Table Employee
(
        Employeeid int primary key,
        EMPname varchar(50),
        ManagerEmplId int reference key Employee (EmployeeID)
         TreeLevel int,
              ....
)
```

Here i need to find all leaf level employees.

Leaf Level Employees - All employees who have manager but they do not have anybody reporting to them.  I have a little help from db which has TreeLevel column where I can specify pick anybody at level 3 but I need a UNIONclause which will get me all employees at treelevel 2 that do not have any employees reporting.
I have only 3 levels of tree if that helps in creating linq query.

```
   return ((from b in _db.Employees
                && b.TreeLevel==3 && b.DeletedDate== null
                    select b)
                    .Union
                    (from b in _db.Employees

                     select b)

                    )
                    .ToDictionary(k => k.EmployeeID, v => v.EMPname);
```

**UPDATE:**
The real query:

```
(from fi in firm 
 join bra in _db.Branches on fi.BranchID equals bra.ParentBranchID into g 
 from sc in g.DefaultIfEmpty() 
 where fi.DeletedDate == null && g == null 
 select fi)
 .ToList()
 .ToDictionary(k => k.BranchID, v => v.BranchName);
```

Error:

```
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. 
Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the right outer join and make sure that the left side is empty.

In this post [How to do a full outer join in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085422/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-linq) you can find a good example of how to do it in linq.

```
from b in _db.Employees
from c in _db.Employees.Where(o=> o.ManagerEmplId == b.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
where c == null
```

Comment: getting exception as follow   Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.

Comment: Here is my original query  I masked my issue withgeneric one but this one is also simple 

return (from b in 
           join firm in _db.Branches on b.BranchID equals firm.ParentBranchID into g
                    from sc in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    wher b.DeletedDate == null && g == null
                    select b).ToList()  
                     .ToDictionary(k => k.BranchID, v => v.BranchName); Getting err Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.

Comment: return (from b in <br/>
          * join firm in _db.Branches on b.BranchID equals firm.ParentBranchID into  <br/>
            *        from sc in g.DefaultIfEmpty()<br/>
             *       wher b.DeletedDate == null && g == null<br/>
              *      select b).ToList() <br/> 
               *      .ToDictionary(k => k.BranchID, v => v.BranchName);<br/>


* Getting error <br/>

* Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.

Comment: replace the `g == null` with `sc == null`.

Comment: how do i format my comments they are looking ugly iam using http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 1):

This query should do the trick, regardless of tree depth:

```
var leafEmps = 
    (from emp in _db.Employees
     where !_db.Employees.Any(e => e.ManagerEmplId == emp.EmployeeId)
     select emp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var managersids = _db.Employees.Select(emp => emp.ManagerEmplId ).Distinct();
var leafemps = _db.Employees.where(emp => !managersids.contains(emp.Employeeid));
```

To do this simple, get all the managers and then search the people who arn't a manager

```
var leafemps = from emp in _db.Employees
               let managersids = _db.Employees.Select(emp => emp.ManagerEmplId ).Distinct()
               where !managersids.contains(emp.Employeeid)
               select emp
```

Comment: When changed code as per suggestion i am getting following error                                                              Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: Ok then, to bad i couldn't help