# How to merge (REMEMBER merge not combine!) these two queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have these two linq queries:

```
var combo1 = from c in db.comments
             join p in db.picture on c.targetpictureid equals p.idpictures
             join u in db.users on c.iduser equals u.iduser
             select new TCommentDTO
             {
                 idcomments=c.idcomments,
                 comment1 = c.comment1,
                 targetpictureid = c.targetpictureid,
                 ctime = c.ctime,
                 iduofpic=p.iduser,
                 iduofcommentor=c.iduser,
                 profilepicofcommentor=u.profilepic,
                 usernameofcommentor=u.username,
                 picFilename=p.picFilename,
                 picTitle=p.picTitle
             };

var combo2 = from f in db.followers
             join u in db.users on f.iduser equals u.iduser
             select new TfollowerDTO
             {
                idfollowers = f.idfollowers,
                iduser = f.iduser,
                targetiduser = f.targetiduser,
                startedfollowing = f.startedfollowing,
                unoffollower = u.username,
                ppoffollower = u.profilepic,
                status = u.status
             };
```

I am using web API that returns JSON. I want to merge the output of these two queries.

I want to rewrite this code in such a way that comments and follower data should be merged (not combined) with respect to time based on `ctime` and `startedfollowing`. If a user has a new comment, the comment should come first and if the follower is first, the follower data should come first.I can not use Union() and Concat() because firstly both classes have different members and secondly i dont want both json object to be combined.

Something like this:

```
{ //comments data },
{ //follower data},
{ //comments data },
{ //comments data },
{ //comments data },
{ //follower data}
```

So how to do this task?

Comment: Do you know about `Union()`?

Comment: Yeah i do know about Union() and Concat(), but cant use them, because firstly both classes have different members and secondly i dont want both json object to be combined.

Comment: It sounds like you have to [full outer join](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2085422/1043380) your two queries, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think joins will not work

Comment: Other than printing them out and using duct tape, I don't get how the two result sets can relate to each other... Are they bound by one of the many `userid`s ?

Comment: Yeah they are bound by userid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
public class TDtoWrapper
{
    public DateTime SortKey {get;set; }
    public Object Member {get;set;}
}


var result1 = from c in combo1
              select new TDtoWrapper { SortKey = c.ctime, Member = c }

var result2 = from c in combo2
              select new TDtoWraller { SortKey = c.startedfollowing, Member = c }

var result = result1.Concat(result2).Orderby(x => x.SortKey).Select(x => x.Member);
```

if you can rewrite the origninal queries, you can ommit the Dto class and write

```
var combo1 = from c in db.comments
             join p in db.picture on c.targetpictureid equals p.idpictures
             join u in db.users on c.iduser equals u.iduser
             select new 
             { 
                SortKey = c.ctime, 
                Member = (object) new TCommentDTO
                {
                  idcomments=c.idcomments,
                  comment1 = c.comment1,
                  targetpictureid = c.targetpictureid,
                  ctime = c.ctime,
                  iduofpic=p.iduser,
                  iduofcommentor=c.iduser,
                  profilepicofcommentor=u.profilepic,
                  usernameofcommentor=u.username,
                  picFilename=p.picFilename,
                  picTitle=p.picTitle
                 }
             };


var combo2 = ...

var result = from c in combo1.Concat(combo2)
             orderby c.SortKey
             select c.Member;
```

Comment: i think you have reached there, let me try it...

Comment: I am getting this error while implementing your solution, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<object>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyProjecct.Models.TCommentDTO>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: solved that, now getting a runtime error :DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible collection ResultTypes

Comment: Can't tell where excatly this happens, but you can try `somelinquery.Cast<object>()`