# What would be the correct syntax for a full outer join in linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm new to linq and I'm having trouble getting the correct syntax for this sql statement.

```
SELECT
    A.AssetName,
    B.MPercentage,
    B.OPercentage,
    B.IsStateDefault,
    D.ShortName
FROM [Core].[dbo].[Asset] A
FULL OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[PayrollMarkup] B
ON A.PayrollMarkupID = B.PayrollMarkupID
FULL OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[StatePayrollMarkup] C
ON B.PayrollMarkupID = C.PayrollMarkupID
FULL OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[StateLookup] D
ON C.StateID = D.StateID
WHERE A.AssetName IS NOT null
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure LINQ doesn't have a full outer join.

Comment: There are **[many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085422/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-linq) [ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join)** of doing it.

Comment: Additionally, I don't think it is the correct solution here.  if A.AssetName cannot be null, the first join should be a LEFT JOIN.  Plus, performing the additional joins after the first will be difficult if no `Core` is found.  What are you really trying to do?  There is probably a better way in SQL and LINQ.

Comment: I'm trying to get back a list of Assets with their MPercentage, OPercentage and the ShortName.

If no PayrollMarkup, StatePayrollMarkup or StateLookup exist, I would still like the AssetName returned with null for the remaining values.

Comment: sounds like all of that should be left joins.